# A linear transformation is correct iff its standard matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> We say that a linear transformation $T : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ is *correct* if $$\{ x \in \Bbb R^n: T({\bf x}) = {\bf 0} \} = \{ {\bf 0} \}$$ Show that $T$ is *correct* if and only if $A_T$ is invertible.

---

My understanding of the definition is that the only vector that becomes the zero vector after the transformation is the zero vector itself.

But how would I use that to show that $T$ is *correct* if and only if $A_T$ is invertible? Is it because if $A_T$ is invertible then $A_T {\bf x} = {\bf 0}$ only has the trivial solution, and that satisfies the definition of $T$ being *correct*?

Comment: What are $T$ (linear map from where to where?) and its "standard matrix" $A_T?$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the nullity of an invertible matrix 0?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2760404)

Comment: @AnneBauval would the statement if n > m then any transformation T:R^n -> R^m is not correct?

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Comment: @checkfirst You did not answer the questions of my comments. Moreover,  your (not so clear) comment seems to ask a question distinct from that of your post.

Comment: For that new question (as far as I understand it), see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2797268/386889 since you "correctness" is equivalent to *injectivity* of the linear map.

Answer (score -1):

Multiply both sides by $A_T^{-1}$.

BTW, this statement is true only if the dimension of the domain and codomain are equal. If we have $T: \mathbb R \rightarrow  \mathbb R^2$ where $T(x) = [x,x]$, then $T$ is "correct", but its matrix is not invertible.

Comment: You are not proving the "iff", and this is a duplicate.